# Why does the first query sends blank data in database and others work fine?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written following query. br_name should be added to br_name in brand table but br_name gets blank field in database
Meanwhile other queries work just fine.

I have tried following code which doesn't work

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO brand_sector (bs_name,v_name) VALUES ('" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO brand(bs_id) SELECT brand_sector.bs_id FROM brand_sector WHERE brand_sector.bs_name = '" + TextBox6.Text + "' AND brand_sector.v_name = '" + TextBox7.Text + "' ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO brand (br_name) VALUES ('" + TextBox5.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I want br_name to be inserted in br_name in brand table

Comment: try printing values first and check why it is getting as null.. print TextBox5.Text

Comment: Well What do you think is causing the problem ?

Comment: what value you're getting after printing TextBox5.Text  to console ?

Comment: i am getting blank. not even 0